# Selecting active RC integrator values such that the circuit properly integrates

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrator

I'm designing an active RC integrator, using the multiple feedback low-pass filter topology (working using the same principles) and I'm having some real trouble understanding why sometimes the thing does not integrate.

I do all my calculations and simulate, it does not integrate the signal. I have kind of sussed out that the feedback capacitor has to be <10nF to start integrating. I find the better the thing integrates the more out of wack my phase angle goes. My frequency of interest is 50/60Hz and the device should work from 10-10kHz* @ 3 degree phase error at 40-70Hz and 15~degree for the rest.
The input voltage is being fed off a buffer opamp supplying for about 30uV (worse case) to about 1V .

I calculate the time constant for the frequency of interest and design the RC filter accordingly. If the RC is much lower it does not integrate and if its any higher the phase angle goes wacky the integration is not clean.

Any advice on how to tackle this - should I set the RC time constant much higher than the frequency of interest, and how do I fix the phase angle?

Circuit im using is below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzQ3yk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

p.s 
Im using the following links to aid in my development if anyone is intrested
http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPtazyuLowkeisan.htm
http://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-220.pdf

Comment: Phase shifts take +/- 2decades about the breakpoint to each <1% error so choose the amount of phase error and 0.5 Hz breakpoint. Why are you not integrating?

Comment: A perfect integrator works from DC to infinity. Why do you want to distort the result?

Comment: sid830, your text is confusing. Do you intend to create an inverting MILLER integrator? Why do you mention "multiple feedback low-pass" and "RC filter" ? Please note that an IDEAL integrator cannot be realized. More than that, an integrator for the range 10Hz ---1kHz is also hard to realize - in particular for the lower frequency region! Show us your circuit and specify your requirements (with allowable errors).

Comment: Show the circuit.

Comment: Updated (Added circuit and specs im trying to design)

Comment: Tony - I dont want to distort the result! Im trying to intergrate perfectly without my phase angle going all wacky!

Comment: what do you consider as "integrating" or "not integrating"? It sounds like your circuit it working, you are just changing the cutoff frequency and gain. Consider than an integrator is a lowpass filter.